# node orm for postgres groupby is not giving grouped results set

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) (the Filtering and sorting section) I have tried:

```
Person.findAsync({status:'active',form:'success'}, {groupBy:'permission'})
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    })
```

;
But it's not considering `groupBy` at all. What am I doing wrong?
I am using Postgresql as my database.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. Have you checked case-sensitivity? Is `permission` the *exact* name of the column?

Comment: Yes,I have already checked about case sensitivity.But still its not considering the group by.If possible can you please try with your sample data and kindly let me know your output

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] including simple data scheme and data itself (4-5 lines would do)? You see, you can never be sure there's no bug in the lib itself. And when you try to minimize the code that reproduces the issue, you usually find something (if you compare the results on each iteration of simplifying)